# How can I define lifecycleaware coroutinescope for activity or application in composable function?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-lifecycle, kotlin-flow

Let says I have splash Screen:

```
@Composable
fun SplashScreen(viewModel: SplashViewModel = hiltViewModel()) {
    
    val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current
    val externalsomeScope="?"
    viewModel.transferScopeRepoistory(externalsomeScope )
       
}

class MyRepository{
    fun saveToDb(val scope: CoroutineScope,){
     scope.launch{
               //save to Room
         
            }.join()
         }
     }
```

For datasycn at background (retrieving data server and save to database), I want  application to continue operation at background (usually referred as when application rotate, compose function recompose and make service call again).In Splash screen example, lifecycle owner is composable function. How to define activity(or application) lifecycleaware scope and pass to repository where operations happen.Are there any drawbacks like memory leaks etc.How should be coroutine handled in repository?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can just use `LocalLifecycleOwner.current.lifecycleScope` to get lifecycleAware coroutineScope.
2. You can use [ProcessLifecycleOwner](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ProcessLifecycleOwner)

If you do need some kind of short background job. I would recommand to use [`viewModelScope`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#viewmodelscope). `viewModelScope` has much longer lifetime, because `viewModelScope` won't be cancelled even when recreation happens.

Actually injecting `CoroutineScope` like you've posted is not a correct way for launching background job. It will call `transferScopeRepoistory` every time when `SplashScreen` recompose. Moreover, if let your activity to recreate, than any `LocalLifecycleOwner` also recreates.(`Fragment`, `NavBackStackEntry`, `Activity`)

Comment: I just was looking for like a sync module NowInAndroid sample of And devs but it is too compliated for my project because it includes work manager etc. All I need an activity aware scope but when I look architecture hieracy it look like scope should be initiliazed as app starts because data level should not send init command to app etc. and I am not experienced in life of scope in a big project. Therefore I am not sure memory leaks maybe later cause problem.What do you think?Should I define viewmodelscope in activityviewmodel and and pass it and use it everytime?Do you think it cause problem.

Comment: @yardımcıEtis  viewModel is persist even when configuration changes( e.g rotation, multiwindow, popup and so on). So using any kinds of viewModelScope shouldn't be the problem. But if you want activity level viewModelScope, I would suggest to define `CompositionLocal` and provide activitityLevel scope to the child composable.

Comment: Thank you I will look into `CompositionLocal`